# jQuery expanded Datatable trying to get Data from Laravel variable

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatables

I'm trying to pass data to jquery Datatable from a variable that passed from a controller to view with compact() function, but I'm facing the problem of:
DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7

Controller

```
public function show(Expense $expense)
    {
        $expenseTypes = ExpenseType::all()->sortBy('label');
        $charges = json_encode($expense->charges());
        /*$charges = $expense->charges()->get();*/
        return view('expenses.show', compact('expense', 'expenseTypes', 'charges'));
    }
    }
```

HTML

```
 <table class="table m-b-0 table-hover expand-table dataTable table-custom">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th></th>
                                            <th style="width: 5%">id</th>
                                            <th>date</th>
                                            <th>description</th>
                                            <th>details</th>
                                            <th style="width: 25%">observation</th>
                                            <th>sum</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        

                                    </tbody>
                                    <tr class="bg-light">
                                        <td colspan="4"></td>
                                        <th class="text-nowrap" scope="row">{{ __('all.total sum')}}</th>
                                        <td colspan="1"><b>{{ $expense->charges()->sum('sum') }} <small>MAD</small></b></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
```

Jquery

```
<script>
        /* Formatting function for row details - modify as you need */
        function format ( d ) {
            // `d` is the original data object for the row
            return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">'+
                '<tr>'+
                '<td>description:</td>'+
                '<td>'+d.description+'</td>'+
                '</tr>'+
                '<tr>'+
                '<td>details:</td>'+
                '<td>'+d.details+'</td>'+
                '</tr>'+
                '<tr>'+
                '<td>observation:</td>'+
                '<td>'+d.observation+'</td>'+
                '</tr>'+
                '</table>';
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
            var table = $('.expand-table').DataTable( {
                serverSide: false,
                "ajax": {
                    "url" : "{{$charges}}",
                    "type" : "POST"
                },
                "columns": [
                    {
                        "className":      'details-control',
                        "orderable":      false,
                        "data":           null,
                        "defaultContent": ''
                    },
                    { "data": "id" },
                    { "data": "date" },
                    { "data": "description" },
                    { "data": "details" },
                    { "data": "observation" },
                    { "data": "sum" }
                ],
                "order": [[1, 'asc']]
            } );

            // Add event listener for opening and closing details
            $('.expand-table tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
                var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
                var row = table.row( tr );

                if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
                    // This row is already open - close it
                    row.child.hide();
                    tr.removeClass('shown');
                }
                else {
                    // Open this row
                    row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
                    tr.addClass('shown');
                }
            } );
        } );
    </script>
```

Comment: this error comes when there is mismatch between table header count and data specified in the columns or if any of the json key is missing. where are you passing the data?

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to pass `null` as key to the first column data, use `id` or any other valid key which is present in the passed JSON data. This error comes when key is not available in the passed json OR column count in header and data does not match.

```
"columns": [
                    {
                        "className":      'details-control',
                        "orderable":      false,
                        "data":           'id', /// instead of 'null use id
                        "defaultContent": ''
                    },
                    { "data": "id" },
                    { "data": "date" },
                    { "data": "description" },
                    { "data": "details" },
                    { "data": "observation" },
                    { "data": "sum" }
                ],
```

Comment: Thank you but this is not the problem and it's not working, this column has to be null because it's for the expand button

Comment: can you recreate the issue on code snipped or jsfiddle so that i can take a look at it

Comment: I didn't understand what are you talking about?